# XCode C++ source code print issue on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am using MacBook Pro Mac OS 10.5 with related version of XCode. I am new to this development environment. I am developing C++ console/terminal applications (File->New project, then from the list on the left "Command line utility", and on the right "C++ tool".).

For C++ source code file, I want to print source file content with line number. Any ideas how to do this?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article [A Recipe to Pretty-Print Your iPhone Source in Xcode](http://richard.milewski.org/archives/224) it uses enscript which is installed by Apple for Xcode on Snow Leopard so no need for macports etc.

You can get linenumbers by passing -C as an argument to the enscript executable called in the shell script

Comment: I am using Mac OS 10.5, and I think it should be called "Leopard", other than "Snow Leopard"? Does this method also works for me?

Comment: In general yes - the only difference might be that enscript is not installed bu Apple if it is it is /usr/bin/enscript - if not then you need to install it either directly compiling or via macports, fink etc